# will_paginate helper undefined in sinatra with mongoid

Tags: ruby, sinatra, mongoid, will-paginate

I am using sinatra 1.4.3 and mongoid 3.1.4. I tried adding will_paginate gem from master branch for mongoid support so I added this to my gemfile:

```
gem 'will_paginate', :git => 'git://github.com/mislav/will_paginate.git', 
                     :branch => 'master'
```

In environment.rb I added:

```
require 'will_paginate'
require 'will_paginate/mongoid'
```

And pagination method started working. I have still problem with will_paginate helper. In my views I get errors like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `will_paginate' for #<Class:0x006ff5df8578b0>
```

Am I missing something for helper to work under sinatra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it's best solution but adding

```
include WillPaginate::Sinatra::Helpers
```

in my controller solved my problems.

Comment: where did you put this line?

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem, I'm using Datamapper.